# getting error " Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer entity.AddressEntity.addressId] by reflection for persistent property "

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I have two entity models named EmployeeEntity and AddressEntity. EmployeeEntity is in One to Many relationship with address entity. When I am inserting the data in EmployeeEntity it is throwing an error.

`Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer demo.entity.AddressEntity.addressId] by reflection for persistent property [demo.entity.AddressEntity#addressId] : demo.entity.AddressEntity@9fa01480`

My AddressEntity is:

```
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "address_entity")
public class AddressEntity {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer addressId;
    
    public Integer getAddressId() {
        return addressId;
    }
    public void setAddressId(Integer addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String pinCode;
}
```

My EmployeeEntity is :

```
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "employee_entity")
public class EmployeeEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer empId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String designation;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="empId")
    private List<AddressEntity> address;
}
```

My DAO method is:

```
public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EmployeeEntity employeeEntity=dozer.map(employee, EmployeeEntity.class);
        
        entityManager.persist(employeeEntity);
        
    }
```

My service method is :

```
public String addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        
        employeeDao.addEmployee(employee);
        return "Added Successfully";
    }
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated: You seem to be missing a `@ManyToOne` annotation in your `AddressEntity`

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace?